# how can I add icon for attachment in mesibo UI messagens in android SDK?

Tags: android, user-interface, message, mesibo

i'm trying to add voice code uisng MesiboUI Config but there is no affect in UI I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a file handler.

See code here, it checks if the file handler is implemented or not. If not, it hides attachment buttons.

https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/master/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/MessagingFragment.java#L476

Comment: how to implement  file handler ??

Comment: Refer to the sending file section here https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/